# How to print two different texts using the same div tag in the same file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div tag

```
  <div id="generic" style="color:red;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold"></div>
```

To print the text at that position I am using

```
 document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML= "Please wait";
```

At the same position I need to print a different message in the same file

```
document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML= "Processing done";
```

Since there are two different messages being printed using the same div tag at different instants in the same file,it is getting overwritten and only the second message is getting displayed..

Can someone suggest how this can be rectified to get both the texts...

Comment: You could change to `+=`, but there are quite a few things you could improve here.

Comment: += might not be suitable since I want the first message( please wait) to be displayed and later in place of that the new message needs to be displayed (processing done)

Comment: I want the new text to replace the first one and not be appended to the first...

Comment: Can someone suggest how  to get the initial text(please wait) first and later the second text(processing done) must replace the first text and not get appended to the first?

Comment: @shreya: In your question it seemed like it was unwanted that it was getting overwritten, but now you're asking for us to show you how to overwrite it? (which you have already accomplished) Please explain what you want in a clear way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to append?

```
  document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML= "Please wait"; 
  //sometime later
  document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML+="Processing done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this, so it will add the second text to the first text (note the `+` operator):

```
document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML = "Please wait";
document.getElementById("generic").innerHTML += "Processing done";
```

You could also store the `generic` element in a variable to make your code shorter, like this:

```
var genericElement = document.getElementById("generic");
genericElement.innerHTML = "Please wait";
genericElement.innerHTML += "Processing done";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the innerHTML as you normally would when concatenating strings.

```
document.getElementById('generic').innerHTML = 'Please wait';
document.getElementById('generic').innerHTML += 'Processing done';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to **know** how much time is **between** the two messages. With **setTimeout()** you can do something like this:

```
function setText(id, message) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.innerHTML = message;
}

var time = 1000; // Time between the two messages

setText("generic", "Please wait"); // First message
setTimeout(function() {
    setText("generic", "Processing done"); // After one second run second message
}, time);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq6qhhhu/1/)